# What is the difference between distribution function and density function?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, inference, random-variable

What is the difference between Density function and Distribution function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are the terms probability density function and probability distribution (or just "distribution") interchangeable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174515/are-the-terms-probability-density-function-and-probability-distribution-or-just)